# RangError on updating an old document after updating schema in meteorjs ( Yogiben Admin, Simpleschema )

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im getting the following error

W20151027-20:28:24.193(5.5)? (STDERR) 
W20151027-20:28:24.195(5.5)? (STDERR) /private/var/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.13atstp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151027-20:28:24.196(5.5)? (STDERR) throw(ex);
W20151027-20:28:24.196(5.5)? (STDERR) ^
W20151027-20:28:24.196(5.5)? (STDERR) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
=> Exited with code: 8

say I have a simpleschema with field "a", and I have inserted data to it using the admin panel. After that, I have added another field "b", and edited the existing document in the collection using the admin panel to add value for the field "b", and it throws the above error.

But if I try to insert a new document, there is no error. A bit stuck on this. !! Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the new field is optional in the schema, the old documents can't be validated against it anymore, probably somewhere in the process of updating it via the admin panel.